# ALTER DATABASE failed because a lock could not be placed on database '<db_name>'. Try again later

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I really don't care what I do with this test database...it's for sandbox testing (*attached to a production server instance*)! All I'm trying to do is KILL all connections, drop and create test_db, if not asking for to much....and restore with some test data.

I've tried  `USE [MASTER] RESTORE DATABASE test_DB WITH RECOVERY GO` , but got this error:

> Msg 3101, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Exclusive access could not be obtained because the database is in use.
>   Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

Also,  tried
 `USE [master] ALTER DATABASE test_DB SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE;`, and got error:

> Msg 5061, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   ALTER DATABASE failed because a lock could not be placed on database 'test_DB'. Try again later.
>   
> Msg 5069, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   ALTER DATABASE statement failed.

Also did
`select min(spid)  from master..sysprocesses  where dbid = db_id('test_DB')`, but my result set returned `NULL`

Below is my code:

```
 --- Kill Connections
    USE [master] 

    DECLARE @cmdKill VARCHAR(50)

    DECLARE killCursor CURSOR FOR
    SELECT 'KILL ' + Convert(VARCHAR(5), p.spid)
    FROM master.dbo.sysprocesses AS p
    WHERE p.dbid = db_id('test_DB')

    OPEN killCursor
    FETCH killCursor INTO @cmdKill

    WHILE 0 = @@fetch_status
    BEGIN
    EXECUTE (@cmdKill) 
    FETCH killCursor INTO @cmdKill
    END

    CLOSE killCursor
    DEALLOCATE killCursor 

    --Drop and Create 

    USE [master]
    GO

    IF  EXISTS (SELECT name FROM sys.databases WHERE name = N'test_DB')
    DROP DATABASE [test_DB]
    GO

    USE [master]
    GO


        CREATE DATABASE [test_DB] ON  PRIMARY 
        ( NAME = N'test_db_Data', FILENAME = N'\\some_place\d$\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA\test_DB.mdf' , SIZE = 125635136KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 20%)
         LOG ON 
        ( NAME = N'test_db_Log', FILENAME = N'E:\SQLLogs\test_DB.ldf' , SIZE = 1064320KB , MAXSIZE = UNLIMITED, FILEGROWTH = 20%)
        GO

    ALTER DATABASE [test_db] SET ....
```

Answer (score 1):

A database cannot be taken offline if there are still open connections to it.

Also, make sure your connection is not using that DB (`USE master`) then use the `WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE` option of the `ALTER DATABASE` to take it offline.

Answer (score -1):

Do you know who is connected?

```
SELECT 
    DB_NAME(dbid) as 'DBName'
    , loginame as 'Login'
    , COUNT(dbid) as 'Connections'

FROM
    sys.sysprocesses
WHERE 
    dbid > 0
GROUP BY 
    dbid
    , loginame
```

Comment: To get a list of dbid's 

SELECT 
 
     name
 
     , dbid

FROM 
 
     master.dbo.sysdatabases

order by
 
     name